# Access rails console in aws docker container

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, docker

I recently was given a project that is hosted in docker containers on AWS.

I do a lot of bugfixing where having access to `rails console` is *super* useful. For heroku projects, I run `heroku run rails console`. For AWS (non docker) I ssh in and run `bundle exec rails console`. I'm a docker noob so I don't know how to work with containers.

Is there any way I can access `rails console` in these containers?

Answer (score 1):

Generally you can just attach to the docker container and run all the commands you want. 
The details depend a little on how the container is started initially.

`sudo docker container ls` should give you a good starting point though.

You can then attach to the container using `docker attach...` and run the commands you want. 
Another alternative is using `docker exec` on the container [see here.](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/)